# Accordion and Data Tables

Tags: datatables, accordion

If i use both Accordion and Data Tables to gather Data table is not working is there any way to solve this problem to use both accordion and data tables to gather in a process

Script for data tables

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;
 
            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };
 
            // Total over all pages
            total = api
                .column( 4 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                } );
 
            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 4, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Update footer
            $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(
                '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
            );
        }
    } );
} );
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

```html
HTML Code
<body>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
 
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
 
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger</td>
                <td>Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett</td>
                <td>Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton</td>
                <td>Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric</td>
                <td>Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi</td>
                <td>Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle</td>
                <td>Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod</td>
                <td>Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona</td>
                <td>Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen</td>
                <td>Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya</td>
                <td>Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena</td>
                <td>Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn</td>
                <td>Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde</td>
                <td>Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley</td>
                <td>Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana</td>
                <td>Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael</td>
                <td>Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul</td>
                <td>Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria</td>
                <td>Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley</td>
                <td>Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai</td>
                <td>Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette</td>
                <td>Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri</td>
                <td>Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar</td>
                <td>Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris</td>
                <td>Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica</td>
                <td>Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin</td>
                <td>Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer</td>
                <td>Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden</td>
                <td>Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona</td>
                <td>Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou</td>
                <td>Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle</td>
                <td>House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki</td>
                <td>Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott</td>
                <td>Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin</td>
                <td>Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena</td>
                <td>Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity</td>
                <td>Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard</td>
                <td>Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope</td>
                <td>Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian</td>
                <td>Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy</td>
                <td>Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson</td>
                <td>Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia</td>
                <td>Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno</td>
                <td>Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura</td>
                <td>Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor</td>
                <td>Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn</td>
                <td>Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge</td>
                <td>Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida</td>
                <td>Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita</td>
                <td>Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer</td>
                <td>Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara</td>
                <td>Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione</td>
                <td>Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael</td>
                <td>Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas</td>
                <td>Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad</td>
                <td>Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael</td>
                <td>Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna</td>
                <td>Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
```

Comment: your question isn't clear to me. you are saying that datatables isn't getting started? or the footer are not correctly calculated? or maybe both?

Comment: if i use accordion datatables isn't getting started and footer are not correctly calculated

Comment: i tried to reproduce the problem here http://jsfiddle.net/9p4px0r6/ but as you can see it is working so i had not succeeded, maybe if you didn't sort it out yet you can put in a fiddle so we can help you

Comment: I use accordion in my navigation and data table in my main page i have included the navigation in all page hence few java scripts and accordion in main page is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in these link.
You haven't add correct link for href attribute and src attribute .
You have missed *https:* part from beloved links.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

You have to add correct link address as beloved.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

also call the js function after loading the js files.

Comment: You don't have added any link

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
                var api = this.api(), data;
     
                // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                var intVal = function ( i ) {
                    return typeof i === 'string' ?
                        i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                        typeof i === 'number' ?
                            i : 0;
                };
     
                // Total over all pages
                total = api
                    .column( 4 )
                    .data()
                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    } );
     
                // Total over this page
                pageTotal = api
                    .column( 4, { page: 'current'} )
                    .data()
                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0 );
     
                // Update footer
                $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(
                    '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
                );
            }
        } );
    } );
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First name</th>
                    <th>Last name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
     
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
     
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger</td>
                    <td>Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett</td>
                    <td>Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton</td>
                    <td>Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cedric</td>
                    <td>Kelly</td>
                    <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>$433,060</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Airi</td>
                    <td>Satou</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>$162,700</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brielle</td>
                    <td>Williamson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>$372,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Herrod</td>
                    <td>Chandler</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>$137,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Rhona</td>
                    <td>Davidson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>$327,900</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Colleen</td>
                    <td>Hurst</td>
                    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>$205,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sonya</td>
                    <td>Frost</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>$103,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jena</td>
                    <td>Gaines</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>$90,560</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quinn</td>
                    <td>Flynn</td>
                    <td>Support Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>$342,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Charde</td>
                    <td>Marshall</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>$470,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Haley</td>
                    <td>Kennedy</td>
                    <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>$313,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tatyana</td>
                    <td>Fitzpatrick</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>$385,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Michael</td>
                    <td>Silva</td>
                    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>$198,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Paul</td>
                    <td>Byrd</td>
                    <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>$725,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gloria</td>
                    <td>Little</td>
                    <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>$237,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bradley</td>
                    <td>Greer</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>$132,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Dai</td>
                    <td>Rios</td>
                    <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>$217,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jenette</td>
                    <td>Caldwell</td>
                    <td>Development Lead</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>$345,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yuri</td>
                    <td>Berry</td>
                    <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>$675,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Caesar</td>
                    <td>Vance</td>
                    <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>$106,450</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Doris</td>
                    <td>Wilder</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>Sidney</td>
                    <td>$85,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Angelica</td>
                    <td>Ramos</td>
                    <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>$1,200,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gavin</td>
                    <td>Joyce</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>$92,575</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jennifer</td>
                    <td>Chang</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>$357,650</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brenden</td>
                    <td>Wagner</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>$206,850</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Fiona</td>
                    <td>Green</td>
                    <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>$850,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Shou</td>
                    <td>Itou</td>
                    <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>$163,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Michelle</td>
                    <td>House</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>Sidney</td>
                    <td>$95,400</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Suki</td>
                    <td>Burks</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>$114,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Prescott</td>
                    <td>Bartlett</td>
                    <td>Technical Author</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>$145,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gavin</td>
                    <td>Cortez</td>
                    <td>Team Leader</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>$235,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Martena</td>
                    <td>Mccray</td>
                    <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>$324,050</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Unity</td>
                    <td>Butler</td>
                    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>$85,675</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Howard</td>
                    <td>Hatfield</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>$164,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hope</td>
                    <td>Fuentes</td>
                    <td>Secretary</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>$109,850</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Vivian</td>
                    <td>Harrell</td>
                    <td>Financial Controller</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>$452,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Timothy</td>
                    <td>Mooney</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>$136,200</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jackson</td>
                    <td>Bradshaw</td>
                    <td>Director</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>$645,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Olivia</td>
                    <td>Liang</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>$234,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bruno</td>
                    <td>Nash</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>$163,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sakura</td>
                    <td>Yamamoto</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>$139,575</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Thor</td>
                    <td>Walton</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>$98,540</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Finn</td>
                    <td>Camacho</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>$87,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Serge</td>
                    <td>Baldwin</td>
                    <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>$138,575</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Zenaida</td>
                    <td>Frank</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>$125,250</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Zorita</td>
                    <td>Serrano</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>$115,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jennifer</td>
                    <td>Acosta</td>
                    <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>$75,650</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cara</td>
                    <td>Stevens</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>$145,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hermione</td>
                    <td>Butler</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>$356,250</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Lael</td>
                    <td>Greer</td>
                    <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>$103,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jonas</td>
                    <td>Alexander</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>$86,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Shad</td>
                    <td>Decker</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>$183,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Michael</td>
                    <td>Bruce</td>
                    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>$183,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna</td>
                    <td>Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```